# "vw" CSS units in calc in Chrome not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, viewport-units

The new `vw` (and `vh`, `vmin` and `vmax`) CSS units are quite useful, as is `calc`. Both work fine in Chrome (the latter prefixed as `-webkit-calc`), but for some reason I've found that `calc` property values including the `v*` units, such as `width: -webkit-calc(95vw - 25em)` yield an invalid property value. Is this just not implemented yet, or the spec, or a bug?

Comment: The spec allows `vw` in `calc`, it’s even used in an example there: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc

Comment: This was a bug in Chrome, but it's been fixed now

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It’s a bug, registered as *[Bug 94158](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94158) - calc isn't working with viewport units*.

Comment: Is the bug fixed? I have to use it, or an alternative, and I can't find another way to do it...

Comment: @Samoth Not as far as I know. In Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m, and I just ran into this issue.

Comment: Correct, this chrome bug is still a bug and is currently not being addressed.

Comment: Looks like this was stealth-fixed - at least it seems to be working in the dev channel for me.

Comment: is this still a problem, how come `height: calc(10000vw / 25vh)` returns zero height?

Answer (score 6):

It's an old bug and has long been fixed, but if you're still supporting older versions of chrome, and specifically encountering this bug in an older version of chromium in an Android tablet you're supporting (as was my case), here's the simple way you can get around this bug:

Use a wrapper that spans the VW you're targeting, and then instead of using the viewport units in the calc(...), use 100%.

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-calc-with-viewport-units-bugged" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.container { 
    width: 100vw; //or height: 100vh, depending on your usecase
}
.inner-calc-with-viewport-units-bugged { 
    width: calc(100% - XXXXX px); //or height: calc(100% - XXpx);
}
```

Comment: According to the current [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) that would have to be `XXXXXpx`.