# in css3, use calc() to center vertically with vh and vw

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, viewport-units

in what has to be a widely used case, using `vh` for height of a `div`, and using `vm` for font size.

### css3

```
div.outer { height: 20vh; }
div.inner { font-size: 3vw; height: auto; }
div.inner2 { font-size: 2vw; }
```

### html - case 1

```
<div.outer>
  <div.inner>center me!</div>
</div>
```

### html - case 2

```
<div.outer>
  <div.inner>center me top!</div>
  <div.inner2>center me bottom!</div>
</div>
```

is there any way to use `calc()` and other `css3` properties to vertically center the `div.inner` within the `div.outer`?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["vw" CSS units in calc in Chrome not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182695/vw-css-units-in-calc-in-chrome-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only use one line you can use `line-height: 20vh;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jxu2T/

Comment: good idea!  unfortunately my real-world use is more complicated.  let me think on this a bit....

Comment: am finding that a combination of `padding-top` and `line-height` successfully solves the problem as I am using it.  thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do which isn't future proof is to use top padding.

Sadly `calc()` [didn't work with](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94158) `vh`, `vm` on Chrome (it was fixed 2014-04-30)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer to your *exact* question, though I thought I'd mention it as a possible alternative.

I'm currently tackling a vertical alignment issue myself and until recently had relied on nasty javascript calculations to get the job done! This falls over if the element or parent elements are hidden.

If you are fine using CSS3, might I suggest looking into box-align?
It seems to do the trick for me.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-align.asp