# Vertical and Horizontal center of divs

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work

```
 <div id="dojam_text_container" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; 
                      margin:auto;  background-color:Blue;">
                      <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
                    <span id="text_dojmovi1" style="">"bla bla bla</span></div>
</div>
```

and this does..

```
 <div style="position:absolute; top:10vw; left:10vh;">
    <div style=" border: dotted red 1px; background-color:white; width:20vw; height:
           20vh; display:table-cell; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; position:relative;">
           <span> I am some centered shrink-to-fit content! 
               <br />
           </span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Give `display:table` to your parent `div`!

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian - See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: yes, oddly enough, vw and vh are acceptable CSS3 sizes. [link](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) However, I'm not exactly sure what the OP is trying to accomplish

Comment: You can also view this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497532/in-css3-use-calc-to-center-vertically-with-vh-and-vw

Answer (score 0):

Give `display:table` to your parent div

```
<div style="position: absolute;display:table;width:300px; height:300px; top:100px; left:100px; background-color:Black;">
 .............
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tqR6/)

[*Docs to understand tabular structure using divs*](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Comment: Don't forget to leave comments after downvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

## Vertical & Horizontal Centering

Common issues:

- Parent do not have a position set
- Ancestors do not have a height or width set

### Solution for child with known dimensions

This is a solution if you need it to be IE6 compatible. If you know the dimensions of the child, then

1. define the height/width of the parent.
2. set the parent's positioning
3. position the child absolutely with top, left being 50%, 50%.
4. add a negative margin to offset the child's height & width

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvP6L/)

```
html, body, div.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5em;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5em;
}
```

### Solution for child with unknown dimensions

This solution will work for IE8+. If you don't know the dimensions:

1. define the height/width of the parent.
2. set the parent's display to table
3. set the parent to vertical align: middle

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvP6L/)

```
div.fluid.parent {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.fluid.child {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

### More Resources

For more resources, see [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)