# How to set the height which depends on window height using css calc()

Tags: html, css

This is my css - see the height property

```
header{
   position:fixed;
   height:50px
}
.block{
   height: calc(100vh - (50px));
}
```

I am getting the result on website

[image: see attachment] 
.

```
.block{
   height: calc(50vh);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["vw" CSS units in calc in Chrome not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182695/vw-css-units-in-calc-in-chrome-not-working)

Comment: Working here http://jsfiddle.net/UF3mb/203/

Comment: this might also help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224411/css-calc-viewport-units-workaround

Comment: Are you sure that isn't just cached CSS?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I don't think you need the brackets around the 50px, 
CSS is capable of doing the math without those.

More to the point: 
calc is a rather new technology, still in the experimental phase. 
So not every browser will support it.

You might want to use the browser prefixes (-moz- and -webkit-)
to continue your experiment.

Also, you should probably take a look at this page: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Browser support is actually very good http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc. No prefixes required