# Why calc is not reevaluated when it is used for font-size?

Tags: css, calc, viewport-units

I tried to use VW and calc together and works but calculated only once: loading time:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJOGbr

```
html{
  font-size: calc( 16px + 2vw ); 
}
```

How can I force to evaluate that calc any time the browser window is resized?
It is evaluated once, but never again.
Without calc, the VM works fine...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? I can't reproduce it in any browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["vw" CSS units in calc in Chrome not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182695/vw-css-units-in-calc-in-chrome-not-working)

Comment: Why are you using calc instead of just `font-size: 3vw;`?

Comment: I would like to calculate such things: font-size: calc( 16px + 2vw );

Comment: I would like to have 16px for mobiles and 24 for HD screens and linear calculation between the 2 values.... Without media queries...

Comment: Not a duplication actually. The formula is working now (did not with versions of last year), but not evaluated more than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you are using an older webkit browser, this problem of not-resizing may occur indeed. [See this post](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/). (Scroll to "Bugs!")

> The support is there in Chrome 20+ / Safari 6+, but it fails in one
>   rather significant way. When the browser window is resized, the font
>   doesn't adjust itself according to the new viewport size. The spec
>   says:
>
> When the height or width of the viewport is changed, they are scaled
>   accordingly. I bugged it. Perhaps not a huge disaster as it's pretty
>   much just us design nerds that go around adjusting browser windows,
>   but still. The font does adjust on a fresh page load.
>
> To fix this issue (allow resizing without page refresh) you need to
>   cause a "repaint" on the element. I used jQuery and just fiddled with
>   each elements (irrelevant, in this case) z-index value, which triggers
>   the repaint.
>
> ```
> causeRepaintsOn = $("h1, h2, h3, p");
>
> $(window).resize(function() {   causeRepaintsOn.css("z-index", 1); });
> ```

**UPDATE**: Don't worry about this anymore and definitely don't be forcing
those repaints. This resizing issue is fixed in Chrome 34+ and Safari
7+. It's not common to change the viewport size on mobile devices, so
I'm not sure if this bug ever effected them or not.

Comment: "Setting the font-size on the html element, it gets overwritten by the brower's default stylesheet." That is incorrect.

Comment: @BoltClock Could you then explain why the browser inspector tool tells me so? (Chrome 43)

Comment: Even if you are using h1 settings, using with calc, the dynamic font resizing stops.

Comment: @user1018074 But why do you need calc? You aren't calculating anything.

Comment: You may be inspecting the h1 and not the html element.

Comment: Yeah, you're inspecting the h1 element. Its own default style is overriding the value that would otherwise have been inherited from the html element. That's what's really being overridden. Styling the html element works fine, and in fact the default 2em is being calculated relative to the 3vw on the html element.

Comment: *EDIT* My bad @BoltClock I understand now. Your last comment is correct indeed.

Comment: But I would like to calculate such things:

     font-size: calc( 16px + 2vw );

Comment: Using 2vm itself is not scaling properly from mobile till HD screens. :(

Comment: I would like to have 16px for mobiles and 24 for HD screens and linear calculation between the 2 values.... Without media queries...

Comment: Did you try setting the value to heading tag directly and not HTML? Without normalising the default em-based font-size will modify te value you put on HTML @user

Comment: Tried everything I could. Please see the original URL.