# Font-size calc dynamic size Safari failing

Tags: html, css, sass, postcss

Im using PostCSS [responsive-type](https://github.com/seaneking/postcss-responsive-type) plugin and the generated code I get is as follows:

```
h1 {
 font-size: calc(28px + 20 * ((100vw - 320px) / 880));
}
```

http://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/WwLBxQ

Works fine in Firefox, Chrome and probably other modern browsers. But safari `Version 9.0.3` fails entirely as evidenced in the Codepen I linked.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is?

edit: I may have found the culprit, it seems vw in conjunction with calc is the issue from what I tried. Is there a way of making it work?

Comment: And which of the parts of the expression fail? You can use simplified values to check if it's the calc function, the vw, the nested parentheses etc.

Comment: Use -webkit- prefix in your css  font-size: -webkit-calc(28px + 20 * ((100vw - 320px) / 880));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the CSS calc() function work for me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108285/why-doesnt-the-css-calc-function-work-for-me) or [CSS calc not working in Safari and fallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443343/css-calc-not-working-in-safari-and-fallback)

Comment: @farshid -webkit prefix does not get recognised by the browser, either Chrome or Safari

Comment: @MrLister I reckon its vw in conjunction with calc is the issue from what I tried

Comment: @farshid According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility), the -webkit- prefix wasn't needed after Safari 6.

Answer (score 11):

If anyone is looking at this in 2020 and feels kind of lost as Safari is still acting funky (especially when dealing with dynamic font sizing) have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/yKgagE?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=675a5283c2c13da85153ec8e18e463bcc010bde8-1580163525-0-AWNJiMlOE6f5GdSM7vTEd_7AofIpowJoe4hzQcM7v-F0XhS65t7_x1UvTYI43olCf49_aNDCZgEp_JH3iFVk9jtyx4aJbiGBAY0a2jOy5kBR9RQi5s4NZFPA0ivWAl3s2lcik2Tl7KsY1cHFEvJ0oQoV95czhMEA_KPGxH-zVZedOk7pdE8mPTDIyyjZkP-pmIk9gVa7nTV7DKYgVZbMORHI2-7gfk6KMSf6fVGazOeSEf5qnEVO2yZOH5KQ17lN7Iinz-dVpVgaHSun4zi2I2RizcnwZgcYScsT-x2fZ4YhEInUbvlqOOaNv5SU6pS3pQPYvcT001DjtqA-ORyGZ6l3NN1x9nJfbqVLmrqScTgz4BPLLJncCocMsTEWyAzeSahy7WM3HYUIAR1rdy8YWqc)

It's not mine but it solved the problem for me by using a

```
min-height: 0vw;
```

on the 'text class'. I ended up using it as a global so I don't need to bring in the class everywhere I want to use it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, literally took me forever to figure out what was going on....

Comment: Any idea why this is fixing it?

Comment: @malte as far as I understand Safari needed a reference point to scale elements in older version. It seems fixed in the current one. 

They kinda 'locked' these values in on load and refused updating them if no height was set. It's the same with images in safari. If you don't set a width (even just on auto) Safari handles them differently from other browsers (squeezing them etc.)

Comment: FYI Sara Soueidan recently posted about this and included an alternative fix using `-webkit-marquee-increment: 0vw;`, which is only supported in Safari. https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/safari-fluid-typography-bug-fix/

Answer (score 2):

`calc` or `vh/vw in calc` may have issues in Safari and android browsers. This is a known issue and it was fixed in Safari 7+ but then there still are few issues reported.

`-webkit-calc` could be used as a fallback and it works fine in Safari.

Example fix for Safari :

```
sometag{
    width: 48%;
    width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px);
    width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px);
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

Source : [SO question : Why doesn't the CSS calc() function work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20453951/2142994)

Another old fix for your reference: [using jQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30478068/2142994)

Refer :

1. [vh/vw](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)
2. [calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)
3. [Safari calc test](http://peter.sh/files/calc.html)

Comment: Calc works fine in Safari, its Calc paired with VW thats troublesome

Comment: Yes, `-webkit-calc` could fix it, then again if its an old Safari then the jQuery solution would be best.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Safari 10.0.1 trying to combine `vw` & `px` units.

Using a `%` font-size value instead of `px` solved this for me.
I'm assuming a base font size of 16px.

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: calc(175% + 20 * ((100vw - 320px) / 880));
}
```

```html
<h1>Responsive title in Safari 10</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this problem, is introducing a pure CSS fall-back, that older browsers that don't support CSS calc would only read.

```
h1 {
 font-size: calc(28px + 20 * ((100vw - 320px) / 880));
 font-size: -webkit-calc(28px + 20 * ((100vw - 320px) / 880));
 font-size: -moz-calc(28px + 20 * ((100vw - 320px) / 880));
}
```

Comment: As someone mentioned in the comments – I believe -webkit-calc doesnt get recognised by safari 6 and upwards – I just want it to work with the latest Safari which is 9

Answer (score 1):

Safari 13.1.1 seems to have an issue again with dynamic font-size (based on calculated viewport width) when resizing. So this would not work:

```
html {
font-size: calc(1em + 1vw)
}
```

A workaround I just found:

```
html {
font-size: 1vw; /* initialise it first without calc() */
}

body {
font-size: calc(1em + 16px); /* 1vw = 1em here and 16px is the default browser value */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed here for Safari 15:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224614